# LSPDFR Spawn Point Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am an LSPDFR developer and I am building a callout. I am trying to get my spawn point to spawn at a certain coordinate. 
I currently have:

SpawnPoint = World.GetNextPositionOnStreet(new Vector3(-2051.99463, 3237.05835, 1456.97021));

This is in C#. I get the error Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'float'. Does anyone know what to do? And I am also writing this in Visual Studio

I have tried removing:
private Vector3 SpawnPoint;

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'J' to the end of each coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old topic, but there are no answer ..
I searched for LSPDFR -An addon for GTAV. I had hoped for a lot of activity
There was not..
Anywitch
Someone may browse for this so i will add the way to do this in LSPDFR
Firstly To get a point inside the game-world:
Press F4
In console write:
PrintInfo
Press Enter
Now you have 3 values that represent a 3Dvector
Z is UP!
Lets say we got
x:111, y:222 z:10

Script:
In your variables define a spawnpoint

```
public Vector3 SpawnPoint;
```

You can now say

```
SpawnPoint = new Vector3(111.0f, 222.0f, 10.0f);
```

and use that as a position for a object.
You can also use an object, Ped, or your player, and set a spawnpoint close by:

```
SpawnPoint = World.GetNextPositionOnStreet(
Game.LocalPlayer.Character.Position.Around(300f));
```

That will make a spawn around 300 world meters from current pos your player is in.
So that is two different ways to make a spawn-position in LSPDFR.

CODE

```
//will spawn a car 10 tiks from player if key J is pressed

using LSPD_First_Response;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Rage;
using Rage.Native;
using LSPD_First_Response.Mod.API;
using LSPD_First_Response.Mod.Callouts;
using LSPD_First_Response.Engine.Scripting.Entities;
using Rage.Attributes;

[assembly: Plugin("spawn car", Description = "spawns a car", Author = "mb")]
namespace Example
{
    public static class SpawnCar
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
          public Vector3 SpawnPoint;
            while (true)
            {
                    if (Game.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.J))
                    {
                      SpawnPoint = World.GetNextPositionOnStreet(
                      Game.LocalPlayer.Character.Position.Around(10.0f));
                      aaVehicle = new Vehicle("BALLER", SpawnPoint);//100 of cars are available

                    }

                GameFiber.Yield();
            }
        }
    }
}
```